# I need to extract the data from soup item

Tags: beautifulsoup

I need to get the data from soup item

I tried some of the python code but did not work - I am new to python

```
import bs4
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://finviz.com/futures_performance.ashx')

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")

soup.find_all('script')[14].text.strip()
```

I need to get the data like the following format from
'var rows', `{"ticker", "label","group", "perf"}`)

Comment: Please describe how it did not work; what did you expect, and what did you see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data on this page is loaded through AJAX from different URL (JSON message). We can use Python's builtin `json` module to parse it. The data you want is in variable `data`. I use it to pretty-print the values:

```
import requests
import json
from operator import itemgetter

url = 'https://finviz.com/api/futures_perf.ashx'

data = requests.get(url).json()

# Data is loaded in variable `data`. To print it, uncomment next line:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

print('{: ^15}{: ^15}{: ^15}{: >15}'.format('Ticker', 'Label', 'Group', 'Perf'))
print('-' * 15*4)
f = itemgetter('ticker', 'label', 'group', 'perf')
for ticker in data:
    print('{: ^15}{: ^15}{: ^15}{: >15}'.format(*f(ticker)))
```

Prints:

```
    Ticker          Label          Group                Perf
------------------------------------------------------------
      KC           Coffee          SOFTS                3.09
      6N             NZD        CURRENCIES              0.24
      GC            Gold          METALS                0.13
      HO         Heating Oil      ENERGY                0.13
      QA       Crude Oil Brent    ENERGY                0.11
      NQ         Nasdaq 100       INDICES                0.1
      ES           S&P 500        INDICES               0.07
      ZB        30 Year Bond       BONDS                0.06
      ER2       Russell 2000      INDICES               0.06
      DY             DAX          INDICES               0.05
      ZN        10 Year Note       BONDS                0.04
      YM            DJIA          INDICES               0.03
      SI           Silver         METALS                0.03
      DX             USD        CURRENCIES              0.03
      CL        Crude Oil WTI     ENERGY                0.02
      PL          Platinum        METALS                0.01
      ZF         5 Year Note       BONDS                 0.0
      ZT         2 Year Note       BONDS                 0.0
      6A             AUD        CURRENCIES               0.0
      LC         Live Cattle       MEATS                 0.0
      PA          Palladium       METALS               -0.01
      6E             EUR        CURRENCIES             -0.01
      FC        Feeder Cattle      MEATS               -0.02
      6S             CHF        CURRENCIES             -0.03
      ZL         Soybean oil      GRAINS               -0.04
      RB        Gasoline RBOB     ENERGY               -0.04
      6C             CAD        CURRENCIES             -0.05
      HG           Copper         METALS               -0.06
      6B             GBP        CURRENCIES             -0.06
      6J             JPY        CURRENCIES             -0.08
      EX        Euro Stoxx 50     INDICES              -0.17
      VX             VIX          INDICES              -0.19
      RS           Canola         GRAINS               -0.25
      ZW            Wheat         GRAINS                -0.3
      ZM        Soybean Meal      GRAINS               -0.39
      LH          Lean Hogs        MEATS               -0.43
      NKD        Nikkei 225       INDICES              -0.44
      ZO            Oats          GRAINS               -0.44
      NG         Natural Gas      ENERGY               -0.46
      ZR         Rough Rice       GRAINS                -0.5
      ZS          Soybeans        GRAINS               -0.53
      CT           Cotton          SOFTS               -0.58
      ZC            Corn          GRAINS               -0.62
      JO        Orange Juice       SOFTS               -1.89
      SB            Sugar          SOFTS               -2.11
      ZK           Ethanol        ENERGY               -2.76
      CC            Cocoa          SOFTS               -3.08
      LB           Lumber          SOFTS               -3.59
```

The variable `data` is list of items:

```
[
    {
        "ticker": "KC",
        "label": "Coffee",
        "group": "SOFTS",
        "perf": 3.09
    },
    {
        "ticker": "6N",
        "label": "NZD",
        "group": "CURRENCIES",
        "perf": 0.22
    },
    {
        "ticker": "GC",
        "label": "Gold",
        "group": "METALS",
        "perf": 0.13
    },

... and so on.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Andrej, it’s looks the format I want. I checked through my mobile phone. I really appreciate your time and effort. Take care.

Comment: Absolutely wonderful piece of work. I really appreciate your time. How can we get data from this website every minute and write data frame out of that data.

Comment: @Anton Feel free to open new question here on StackOverflow. These comments are not suitable place for it.

Comment: Hi Andrej Kesely Thanks for your help, can you please help me how to get the data from this link https://finviz.com/forex_performance.ashx?v=5. Since I am new user, I have to wait another 5 days to ask a new questions. I need to get the data from the links every minute and write into the data frame. I really appreciate your commitment. Many thanks

Comment: Hi Andrej Kesely, I am really sorry to disrupt you. I have one more question in the forum, I am sure you can help me. please follow this link , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57125985/not-able-to-find-the-data-from-xpath. Many thanks