# Not able to find the data from xpath

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I tried to extract the data every minute and write the data into csv file but I coun't do it. Since I am new to this broad data science world.

I tried findall with soup library but not showing the data.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get('https://finviz.com/forex_performance.ashx')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
forex = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "content "})
print(forex)
```

I would like to get the data like following format
name of the currency and values
example
   GBP                     0.27

Comment: content is a single node so find would have been sufficient (assuming content not dynamic). However, I suspect that is not the node you are after. What is it you want from that content.

Comment: if you look at previous questions you will see you can use something like  table = pd.read_html('https://finviz.com/forex_performance.ashx')[2]   or soup.select_one('#forex_performance table')   to get the initial table.

Comment: Thanks a lot QHarr, I really appreciate your time and effort. How do I get data from 1 DAY RELATIVE PERFORMANCE  [USD]? many thanks

Comment: There is an API though I don't know if it only works at certain times: https://finviz.com/api/forex_perf.ashx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first part you can use the charts tab and regex out the required javascript object which houses the chart data. You can parse that with `json` library.

```
import re
import json
import requests

r = requests.get('https://finviz.com/forex_charts.ashx')
p = re.compile(r'var tiles = (.*);')
data = json.loads(p2.findall(r.text)[0])
one_day_relative_performance_usd = [(data[item]['label'], data[item]['change']) for item in data]
```

For the second you can use pandas or requests

```
import pandas as pd

table = pd.read_html('finviz.com/forex_performance.ashx')[2]
```

or

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

r = requests.get('https://finviz.com/forex_performance.ashx')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
table = soup.select_one('#forex_performance table')
```

---

There is an API call in the web traffic

```
https://finviz.com/api/forex_perf.ashx
```

but that is currently not working at least in my browser.

Comment: Is this as intended?

Comment: Thanks a lot QHarr, first one is working. I really appreciate your time. If you kind enough can you add how to get this data every minute and write them into csv. Many thanks

Comment: I believe there are existing answers covering this on SO. Also, look at cron such as described here: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/9913/periodically-executing-a-scraping-script-with-python

Comment: Thanks a lot. you are a great helper. I wish you all the best in your future endeavours